# Flurry State level user Details

Tags: android

friend's
       I have configured Flurry Analytics in my application,it points the users in the country well,but here i need to know the detailed view of the state wise users by clicking up the country from map showing but the corresponding users from that state is not showing.

I set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in my manifest file and set `FlurryAgent.setReportLocation(true);`before 
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(Rss_Feed_Grid.this, brown_api); in OnStart() method.
what i need to configure to view detail users by states from the country.

please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry is very serious about privacy of end users. Therefore the state wise information is available only when the number of users of your application exceeds a threshold limit. If your application has limited number of users, this information is not available.

Comment: I don't know, may be a few hundreds or thousands.

Comment: For my new application this information was available when I got 96 users.